# How to prevert others from accessing my application database which is at /data/data/com.xxx/database/test.db

Tags: android, sqlite

When we save our data in android ,we allways save them in sqlite. And the database is allways access to others.How to guarantee the security of these data.

I find some apps`database is only access to themself,and when you try to open their database,it will say 'An error occurred while opening the database,unable to open the database file'

PS:I use 'Root Explore' to open the xxx.db

Comment: when I move this database to other folder,and then it will say 'database disk image is malformed:,while compilling:select * from sqlite_master where type in('table','view') order by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root access allows the user of the device, or an app granted admin permissions to access every file on the device, so you can't "hide" any file on rooted files.

If this db has data you want to keep secret you must encrypt it, see this project:
http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

It is accessible to others because your device is rooted and rooting means being able to grant super user privileges which is normally not available to applications. On "normal", not rooted devices these files are not accessible to other applications. If you want to prevent content peeking on on rooted devices too, you need to encrypt your database

Comment: But why some apps can make it unreachable(on rooted devices)

Comment: it should not happen. Once you got root you got highest privileges on the device. You basically are able to do anything. So be more specific on these "some apps", but I suspect you may not be able to access them due to i.e. exclusive locks or similar mechanisms.

Comment: When I use 'wechat'(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tencent.mm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50ZW5jZW50Lm1tIl0.).I found I could not open its database. How do they do this?

Comment: Ensure this application is not running - see in Settings -> apps -> runnning applications and kill it if it is present. Or user OS Monitor to do that.